# SPFx webpart onBeforeDelete?

Tags: spfx

I need the ability to perform file cleanup when a client-side web part is deleted from the page. How can I listen for the delete event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override the Dispose() method on BaseClientSideWebPart.  Make sure you call the base implementation as well.

```
protected dispose(): void
{
  // Do something interesting
  Log.warn("HelloWorld", "Cleaning up my stuff", this.context.serviceScope);

  // call the base class.
  super.dispose();
}
```

Note however, there there is a currently a bug where this code doesn't necessarily get called.  That will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, Pat. I'm still wrapping my head around Typescript so what you're saying makes sense in theory but could you provide sample code that demonstrates how to write this?

Comment: Thank you, I logged on here to report the bug you mentioned and found your code sample as well. Looking forward to the fix!

Comment: This now works using Drop 5 of SPFx.